# Why is my layer output not the same dimensions as shown in my model summary?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have managed to create a successful RNN that can predict the next letter in a sequence of letters. However, I can't work out why a solution to a problem I was having is working.

My training data is of dimensions `(39000,7,7)`

My Model is as follows:

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(SimpleRNN(7, input_shape = [7,7], return_sequences = True))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(7)) 
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    adam = optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.001)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    return model


Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
simple_rnn_49 (SimpleRNN)    (None, 7, 7)              105       
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_14 (Flatten)         (None, 49)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_49 (Dense)             (None, 7)                 350       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_40 (Activation)   (None, 7)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 455
Trainable params: 455
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

This works perfectly. My question is, why do I need the flatten layer? When I don't include it I get this model summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
simple_rnn_50 (SimpleRNN)    (None, 7, 7)              105       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_50 (Dense)             (None, 7, 7)              56        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_41 (Activation)   (None, 7, 7)              0         
=================================================================
Total params: 161
Trainable params: 161
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

followed by this error

`ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_41 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (39000, 7)`

My Question is: when the model summary says the output of the dense layer should be (None, 7 , 7) in the second example, and the error message says activation level is expecting exactly such a 3D input, why is the dense layer actually outputting a tensor of shape `(39000,7)` as according to the error message? I realise the flatten() layer solves this by putting everything in 2D, but im confused as to why it doesn't work without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your error statement you can see that the error is caused when checking the **target** dimensions. Your model output without the flatten layer is of the shape `(None, 7, 7)` which is correctly shown in your model summary. The issue here is that your labels are of the shape `(None, 7)`, so Keras throws a `ValueError` (probably during backpropogation) as your labels have one less dimension than the output of your network. Keras was expecting a `(None, 7, 7)` from labels to match the dimensions of your activation layer, but received a `(None, 7)` instead.

That is why using `model.add(Flatten())` before adding the dense layer works fine, as the target dimensions and outputs dimensions are both `(None, 7)`.

Comment: However, I was attempting to resolve a different issue when I became caught in the error. Each time, I was convinced that I was encountering a difficulty as a result of my method. However, after four days of difficulty, I read your post and saw the summary of my model and discovered the issue. Many thanks.